python to contour plot three different densities in 2D
I wanted to plot three 2d densities of n0, n1 and n2 using imshow() command in matplotlib and show their colorbars.
The densities are quite different and even when i normalize them the final image is not a good quality plot. Usually the colors are changing and one can not see the difference.
I also tried to add three densities and then plot, but that also does not work.
Does anybody have a similar experience? Please let me know. Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In order to plot with Python in Matlab, you would need to import numpy matplotlib.pyplot and matplotlib.colors. You would then need to create a grid, define three densities (gaussian distribution), use color normalization, and finally plot everything.
I can't show more without knowing your code.
